# How to get required options in magento to add a product in cart

Tags: configurable-product, custom-options, soap, addtocart

I am trying to add a product to cart in Magento using Magento SOAP v1 API ,but am getting `Please specify the product required option(s).` error message.

```
The call happens like:

        $productArray[] = array(
            "product_id"=>"24",
            "qty"=>1
);
    $resultCartProductAdd = $client->call($session, "cart_product.add", array($shoppingCartId, $productArray));
```

I am unable to figure out how to find out **what all options are needed to add a product to the cart using SOAP v1** . Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: it's not a general option, it is product specific (custom option).

Answer (score 1):

This options are called `Custom Options` in the admin section. They can be retrieved via the soap api if you have the product id.

```
//SOAP V1
$optionResult = $client->call($session, 'product_custom_option.list', 'product_id');
var_dump($optionResult);

//SOAP V2
$result = $proxy->catalogProductCustomOptionList($sessionId, 'product_id');
var_dump($result);
```

http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/catalog/catalogProductCustomOption/product_custom_option.list.html